# Fit linear model with a spatially structured random effect in R

Tags: bayesian, random-effects-model, spatial

There are `n` sampling units (with explicit spatial coordinates `(pos_x[i], pos_y[i]), i = 1..n`). Data is generated as:

```
y = alpha + beta * x + a + eps,
```

where `alpha, beta` are constant variables,

```
x ~ N(0, 1) 
eps ~ N(0, sigma) 
a ~ N(mu, V)
```

Parameter `a` is the spatial random effect, where `mu` is a vector with zero values and `V` is a matrix: `V_ij = s^2 * exp(-d_ij/sc)`, where `s^2` is the variance, `d_ij` is the distance between sampling units i and j, and `sc` is the spatial scale.

**What function in R would you suggest to fit the model and estimate all the parameters, including variance `s^2` and the spatial scale `sc`?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you should be able to model this in [R using JAGS](http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2010/08/20/using-jags-in-r-with-the-rjags-package/).